# Comparing strings from a text file

Tags: c++, linux, text

I am parsing a text file, and for some reason `string::compare()` isn't working as intended.

The text file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WZDWmb56

The read function (called from inside while loop):

```
string StopName = "***";
    bool Person::ReadOnePersonFromFile(ifstream& fin)
    {
        getline(fin,m_name);
        cout << m_name << endl;
        if( m_name == StopName )
            return false;
        fin >> m_id;
        fin.ignore(50,'\n');
        return true;
    }
```

Whenever `"***"` is reached, `if( m_name == StopName )` doesn't return `true`. What is going on?

This function works on Windows (Visual Studio). I am currently compiling this on Linux. Does this have anything to do with how the text is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. I believe this is because of the way newline characters are encoded on Windows.

```
 Windows: \r\n  (CR + LF)
 Linux: \n 
 Mac: \r
```

I had to convert my Windows text file to a Unix text file with `dos2unix`. The program works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing `StopName` rather than `Stop` in your code, so "***" isn't ever checked (assuming that `Stop` and `StopName` aren't the same thing).

Comment: Oops, that was a c/p mistake. It's supposed to be `StopName`